# node mongoose update two collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas, a "projects" schema, and an "applications" schema.

What is the most efficient way of creating a new entry in a collection and updating an existing entry in another collection based on data inside the new entry? Can I avoid making multiple API requests and somehow run a "stored procedure" on the mongoDB end to handle updating the Projects collection when there is a change in the Applications collection?

In this scenario, ideally when an application for a project is created, a new entry is created in the Applications collection and the Project in the Projects collection is updated to reflect the information in the Application.

Can I do this without making multiple api requests?

**Project Schema:**

```
// models product.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32
      },
      applications: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      },
      created_by: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      applicants: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
      }
       }, {timestamps: true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);
```

**Application Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const applicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  applicantId: { 
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  ownerId: { 
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  projectId: { 
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project'
  }
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Application", applicationSchema);
```

Note that these are separate schemas because they each carry around 15 fields, i've trimmed them down to post this question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use hooks for mongoose model, there is a post save hook which you can use on Application model to update Project and increment application count.

EDIT - Added Pseudo Code

1. Project Model

```
// models -> project.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {
    ObjectId
} = mongoose.Schema;

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32
    },
    applications: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    created_by: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    applicants: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

projectSchema.statics = {
    /**
     * Find project by _id
     *
     * @param {ObjectId} _id
     * @api private
     */

    get: function (_id) {
        return this.findOne({
                _id
            })
            .exec();
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);
```

2. Application Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const projectModel = require("./project")

const applicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    applicantId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    ownerId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    projectId: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// Async hook
applicationSchema.post('save', function (doc, next) {
    const relatedProject = projectModel.get(doc.projectId);
    relatedProject.applications++;
    relatedProject.save();
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Application", applicationSchema);
```

Comment: I feel that this is hinting at the right answer - can you demonstrate it?